# How to totally disable select element e.g. refuse to post its value?

Tags: php, html, post

```
<label id = "NS25DATE">
    <select name="date" id = "date" disabled="disabled">
        <option value="58025">09-29-2017</option>
        <option value="58026">09-30-2017</option>
    </select>
</label>
```

The above code is html element,and I disabled it.

```
$date = $_POST["date"]
```

This is php code.

I disabled "select" element totally, the php variable `$date` now should be null, but its value is "58025".

$_POST still pass value.

So what's wrong, how can I solve this problem?

Any suggestion will be appreciate.

Comment: I don't get it in the POST request body as long as it is disabled. Are you certain that it is disabled when the post request is made? Is the form submitted by a submit button or is there some Javascript code that makes the POST request? Also, verify that the value of that variable is null before the POST request is made. (I'm not sure whether PHP retains non-null values through session or not.) Also, you could check the network tab in Developer tools (F12 in browser) to see what is being sent in the post request.

Comment: If it has no value and is disabled (so users can't interact with it), why show it at all?

Comment: I'm sorry, the POST request is disabled indeed, but the SQL query still works though the SQL query includes 'null-value', that's why I come to this question.Thank your suggestion! @NisargShah

Answer (score 0):

The POST request is disabled indeed, but the SQL query still works though the SQL query includes 'null-value', that's why I come to this question.So this question is solved.